# "On Hold" question presented for Editing Review

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm curious, does it make sense to present an edited on-hold/closed question for suggested edit review?  It was not being requested for reopen.

Comment: Doesn't *every* edit on a closed question flag it for reopening?

Answer (score 6):

Closing a question is not necessarily forever. If it *can* be improved, it *should* be.

Comment: Just for curiosity what percentage of on-hold/closed questions ever make it back into active status?

Comment: I don't have exact numbers right now, but I think it's in the neighborhood of 10% or so.